# How do I remove Xubuntu 14.04 without the command line

Tags: system

I would like to know how to remove Xubuntu 14.04 completely from the Computer without using the command line. I want it free of Xubuntu so that I can return this in the shop and buy a new one.

The pre-installed OS is FreeDOS.

Comment: Which Desktop Environment are you using now ? (and if that matters which OS?)

Comment: Xubuntu 14.04 with Xfce.

Comment: If you remove Xubuntu, what will you use then?

Comment: I've managed to remove parts of Xfce and parts of Xubuntu, but not the whole OS.

Comment: The other OS is FreeDOS, and I want to return this computer back to the shop and buy another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot to your live install disk.  Run the `Try` option.  Run `gparted`.  Then `Delete` or `Format` the partition where you installed `Xubuntu`.

If you are running the `FreeDos` os you can boot to it instead of the Live install disk.  Run `gparted` from that session and remove your `Xubuntu` installation.

Comment: Thank you, but I cannot possibly boot to my live disk...

Comment: @NEven I updated my answer after your reference to having `FreeDos` on the system.

Comment: What kind of command should I type using FreeDOS?

Comment: @NEven I'm not familiar with `Freedos` or the tools directly available for it.  But there are many bootable tools you can download for formatting or removing partitions.  The most convenient would be the various Live Disk or bootable Live USB provided by Ubuntu.  Is there a reason why you can't boot to the Disk you used for installing Xubuntu?

Comment: I have no idea. It just wouldn't let me boot into live session...

Comment: @NEven Are you able to download the live Ubuntu install disk (http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).  It will have all the GUI tools you will need for managing your hard disk and removing or reformatting your unwanted partitions.  Other than that you can use the dos commands that are part of your Freedos installation... which by your title, you don't want to do.

Comment: I've downloaded it, but it doesn't work. It wouldn't boot... And I cannot use DOS, as I don't know the commands in order to access gparted.

Comment: @NEven What error message do you get when you try to boot to the Ubuntu Desktop Disc?

Comment: I get the Boot Menu with Xubuntu and FreeDOS

Comment: If you see the other OS's in the Boot menu, you haven't actually booted to the CD.  You'll have to hit the bios option of the computer to choose the boot device... making it your DVD.  If you boot to the Ubuntu DVD you'll have two options, to Try Ubuntu or install Ubuntu.  If you tell us the `make and model` of your computer we should be able to tell you how to select the DVD as the Boot choice.  Booting to the hard drive will show you menu.  Booting to the DVD will show the DVD menu.

Comment: Lenovo Ideapad 310-14ISK

Comment: @NEven When booting hit F1 or F2 as per this information to get to the bios.  http://superuser.com/questions/639399/how-to-access-boot-menu-on-a-lenovo-g500s/879457. While in the BIO set the boot order for your DVD to be the first device.

Comment: Thank you very very much, L.D. James. I've succeeded in installing Ubuntu on my new computer, and there's Wi-Fi.

Comment: You're welcome.  Please consider marking this problem as resolved by clicking the check mark at the answer.  This way others with similar problems can find workable resolutions.